# Is there an open source php script for enabling Facebook and Twitter logins on my web service?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

Basically, as the Title suggests, are there any open source PHP scripts out there that make it any easier to integrate logging into my website with Google, Facebook and Twitter accounts?

Right now, my sites just have a way to create an account with a email address and password, but I need to add the other methods as well.

The site is PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Try the [Facebook Login Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)

Comment: I'm really looking for something more along the lines of what StackOverflow is doing where they can let people sign-up and login using their Facebook or Twitter accounts.

Comment: This question is valuable to others who don't know that you should be searching for php twitter facebook oath as answered correctly below.

Comment: The question **is** a valid one.  However is is not a good match for this site.  Questions here are required to be more specific.  If you had a problem, for example, with one of the implementations;  You tried some methods and they didn't work - then you could come here and post the code you have tried and get feedback.  Code samples are  highly encouraged as they show that the person has actually attempted to solve this issue.

Comment: There could be *many* correct answers to your questions above and it depends on the users opinions.  That is why it is not the right type of question to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Facebook and Twitter use OAuth, for which there are a number of PHP libraries available, you may have better luck googling it like that.

Google uses OpenID, I'm sure a library for that is available too.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I just didn't know the right terminology and how to look this up.  Searching for "php library twitter facebook oauth" put me down the right path.